# Looking for a sci-fi book where the occupants of a house have to solve 10 problems

Tags: story-identification

I have read this book a few years ago, but I do not know when it was written.

The protagonists are an elderly couple (by elderly I mean, more or less, retirement age) and a youngster (probably related to them, I am not sure).

They are solving a number of problems/puzzles/riddles about the house and when they succeed there is a counter then changes number (goes up or down, I do not remember).

After having solved one of the riddles they can go to an alien "forest" of sorts.

In the end they succeed and I believe that the couple are going to get younger (although I am not sure of that part).

Another thing I remember is that it was said in that book that the couple (they were married, I believe) was happy with each other. One of the reasons for that being one went to sleep early whereas the other went to sleep late, and as a result each of them has some time for themselves only.

I would greatly appreciate if someone would find the answer to my question.